# Cordova: How to write native plugins that can repeatedly invoke a Javascript callback?

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins

When developing Cordova plugins, all of the tutorials I have found go something like this:

**File: AwesomePlugin.js**

```
var AwesomePlugin = {
  kungfuGripAction = function(target, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return cordova.exec(
      successCallback,
      failureCallback,
      'AwesomePluginClass',
      'kungfuGripAction',
      [target]
    );
  }
};

module.exports = AwesomePlugin;
```

**File: AwesomePluginClass.java**

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (ACTION_KUNGFU_GRIP.equals(action)) {
        JSONObject target = args.getJSONObject(0);
        if (gripTarget(target)) {
            callbackContext.success("Target successfully gripped.");
            return true;
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Could not grip target.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "INVALID ACTION! " + action);
    callbackContext.error("Invalid action: " + action);
    return false;
}
```

**File: clientCode.js**

```
AwesomePlugin.kungfuGripAction(cobraEnemy, function(ok) { }, function(err) { });
```

In the above code, the callbacks can only be called once and are then disposed. If you attempt to call the `.success()` or `.error()` method of the callback context object, it will not work and you will get a log message:

```
Attempted to send a second callback for ID: AwesomePlugin2982699494<BR>W/CordovaPlugin(976) Result was: "Target successfully gripped."
```

It seems like it is not possible to write a method with a callback that can be called repeatedly seeing as `.success()` and `.error()` are the only documented ways to invoke a callback from within native plugin code. While this is mostly what we want, there are times when we want to have the plugin execute a callback repeatedly. For example:

```
AwesomePlugin.kungfuGripAction(cobraEnemy, function(ok) {
  // After successful grip, punch repeatedly and update life meter.
  AwesomePlugin.punchRepeatedly(cobraEnemy, function(hits) {
    updateLifeMeter(cobraEnemy, hits);
  }, function(err) { });
}, function(err) { });
```

`AwesomePlugin.punchRepeatedly()` above will execute repeatedly (maybe in a separate thread) and call `function(hits)` with each successful execution. If implemented in the de-facto way (using single-use callbacks), you have to either use a loop (which is bad as it is non-async) or tail-call `AwesomePlugin.punchRepeatedly()` in the callback (error-prone).

What would be the correct way to implement `punchRepeatedly()` in native code so that it is able register the callback once and then execute it repeatedly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think, you can use a `pluginResult` with the `keepCallback` property set to `true`.

```
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "YOUR_MESSAGE");
// PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE");
result.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
```

You should be able to invoke the callback several times this way.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The `PluginResult.setKeepCallback(true)` was the key to this.

Comment: @n.abing doesn't this trigger the success callback multiple times by passing status.ok each time you're sending a new callback?

Comment: @TimothyShamilov no it does not do that. It's been a long time since I've written anything in Cordova but IIRC `result.setKeepCallback(true)` only ensures that the callback function is not destroyed when the `result` is destroyed. When in doubt, use the source :)

Answer (score 0):

In jonas's answer, every time you call `sendPluginResult` you have to send the same value. So I changed the PluginResult class to add a method like this:

```
 public void setStrMessage(String strMessage){
    this.strMessage = strMessage;
}
```

This way, I can set the message I want to send to the JavaScript side.

Comment: You should generally avoid modifying framework code directly. When you upgrade your Cordova framework your changes are lost.

You should also not need to change the message in a plugin result as you already set that when you create a new instance and then send it to the callback. The only time you might want to do this is if you are re-using a single instance of `PluginResult` in your plugin, which is also a bad idea.

Comment: You are right.But I mean to reuse the single instance of Pluginresult by setting setKeepCallback (true),so what's the better way to send a different message each time?In swift language I can use an extension

Comment: What do you mean? You don't have to reuse a single instance of `PluginResult`. You can instantiate a new `PluginResult` each time you need to send back a result to the callback and use a different message if you want. Using `result.keepCallback(true)` only tells `callbackContext.sendPluginResult()` to not mark the callback as "used" so that you can reuse the `callbackContext` in sending results again.

Comment: I originally tried to do as you said,but it would only receive the first callback. `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(268)] "First success", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js (268)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Bluetooth435896053 Result was: "Third success"`

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing wrong without any context or sample of your code. But that should not happen if you create a new instance of the `PluginResult` each time you send it via `CallbackContext.sendPluginResult()`. You probably did not call `PluginResult.keepCallback(true)`. As I said above, `keepCallback(true)` only instructs `sendPluginResult()` to not mark the callback as "used" so that you can keep reusing it. You can look at the code for `sendPluginResults()` here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CallbackContext.java#L54

Comment: I got what you said !Did you mean each instance of Pluginresult should setKeepCallback(true)?!Thank a lot 

Comment: Yes, after you create the new instance of `PluginResult` you should use setKeepCallback(true) before using it in `sendPluginResult()`, otherwise you will get the error you described above.